# Archimedean integration of $x^3$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm trying to integrate $x^3$ in the interval $[0,1]$ in a similar fashion to the famous integration of $x^2$ due to Archimedes. It's an exercise on Apostol's Calculus:

> [image]

I did all the intermediate steps but I'm lost at the inequalities part. Here's what I did:

$$S_n>A>s_n$$

$$\frac{b^4}{n^4} [1+2^3+\dots+n^3]>A> \frac{b^4}{n^4}[1+2^3+\dots+(n-1)^3]$$

Using [Nicomachu's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NicomachussTheorem.html):

$$\frac{n^4}{b^4} \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2>A> \left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]^2 \frac{n^4}{b^4}$$

$$\frac{}{} \frac{b^4n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^4}>A>\frac{b^4 n^2(n-1)^2}{4n^4}$$

Which gives me:

$$\frac{b^4(n+1)^2}{4n^2}>A>\frac{b^4 (n-1)^2}{4n^2}$$

But from here, I don't know how to argue that $A$ could only be $\cfrac{b^4}{4}$. I tried to rewrite it as:

$$b^4\cdot \frac{(n+1)^2}{4n^2}>A>b^4\cdot \frac{ (n-1)^2}{4n^2}$$

And thought about taking the limits, but I guess that would be cheating. I'd like to know how to do in Apostol's way. Can you help me?

Comment: Why should taking the limits be cheating ? We can increase $n$ to make the possible interval smaller and smaller.

Comment: But the given inequality at the end is strange, it would be equivalent to $(n+1)^2<(n-1)^2$ ! You have to change the sides; you started with $S_n<A<s_n$ instead of $s_n<A<S_n$

Comment: Or replace $<$ by $>$ which is edited faster ...

Comment: @Peter Yes. A typo. I'll correct it. And I guess it's cheating because Archimedes didn't have exactly the notion of a limit. Besides, Apostol doesn't use it.